# access cloudwatch across different account programmatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, prometheus

I am in process to use prometheus cloudwatch exporter which  can be used for monitoring various AWS accounts. I seen lot of  documentation about configuring single IAM user (**which are not programmetic**) for cross account access but unable to find steps for configuring **programmetic user** to access cloudwatch across various account.
it will be great if someone can provide me pointers for same

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really have a single IAM role being used cross accounts. What you really need is to create an IAM role that can be assumed by a different user account.

Below link would be helpful in defining a role that can be assumed by a different account:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html?shortFooter=true#tutorial_cross-account-with-roles-2

To utilise the cloudwatch exporter, you need to allow the exporter to assume the role in a similar way. You can create these roles quite easily using coding too. Comment with further details on what you need, will help out

Comment: these steps are for non programmetic user. who can visit web console to switch account. again token we received with this approch is valid for some specific time. in our case i need single cloudwatch exporter can use to fetch data from multiple aws account and it should not be having token valid for specific time.